# How to reduce width of data table columns

Tags: 2013, datatable

I have a sharepoint 2013 list. Using data tables am retrieving the list data into a data table. How to reduce the width of particular columns in data table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone know the solution?

Comment: is it javascript ? or C#?

Comment: I have done it using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script to script editor or content editor webpart. Replace the Column name to column name you want to increase the width

```
    <script src="/PublishingImages/javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){$("TH.ms-vh2-nograd:contains('Column 1')").css("width", "350px");

            $("TH.ms-vh2-nograd:contains('Column 2')").css("width", "350px");

             });

    </script>
```

Comment: Not in the form...I need to reduce it in the datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to adjust the column width in data table

**For the first column**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

For more details check [columns.width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

**For a specific column.**

```
   $('#table_1').DataTable({
    columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id' , width: '50px', class: 'text-right' }
    ]
    });
```

Ref: [Setting column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819597/datatables-setting-column-width)

Comment: I have tried this...It dint work

Comment: add your code in your question to can help you accurately